# Send google analytics event in loop

Tags: google-analytics

I'm a newbie in analytics.

I want to track a `record-created` event every time someone creates a time-record in a web application for time-tracking. But the user can also copy a time record to multiple dates which should yield one `record-created` event for each new record.

Would a simple loop work or does google think my events are coming to them too fast? Should I add a `setTimeout`?

```
_.each(dates, function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'record-created');
    // maybe wrap the line above in a setTimeout ?
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[As per documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas):

> Each analytics.js tracker object starts with 20 hits that are
>   replenished at a rate of 2 hit per second. Applies to All hits except
>   for ecommerce (item or transaction).

Plus you have "only" 500 interaction hits per session, so you should not send too many events or GA will drop data.